# Only allow my server to execute a script in PHP

Tags: php, security, nginx, xss, csrf

What is the best way to prevent executing a `PHP` script from other hosts? Basically, I only want my server `web1.mydomain.com` to execute the PHP script. Right now, if I create a html file with an `iframe` or `img tag` that points to my script on a different domain and call it, it works and executes. I want to prevent this.

Is it possible to do this at the web server level instead of PHP application code? I am using `nginx`. That would be the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would seem to be a textbook case of what the `valid_referers` nginx directive is for.

Add something like the following to the `location`-block for your script:

```
valid_referers web1.mydomain.com;
```

or if you want to be bit less strict, and more tolerant of stripped/obfuscated referers:

```
valid_referers none blocked web1.mydomain.com;
```

see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html#valid_referers for more info

Comment: Awesome, `valid_referers` works great. Here is the code: 

valid_referers server_names *.my-domain.io;
if ($invalid_referer) {
      return 403;}

Answer (score 4):

To prevent a page being embedded into a frame outside your domain, you can set the `X-Frame-Options` response header to prevent pages from other domains from embedding it into an iframe (as long as the browser obey).

In nginx you can add this to configuration:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
```

For Apache:

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

---

For `<img>` tag, you can check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    if(preg_match("@^http://web1.mydomain.com($|/.*)@", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) != 1){
        die;
    }
}
```

This method rely on the `HTTP_REFERER` which is set by the user agent. I think this should work in most circumferences. Unfortunately there is no way for me to test.

I think this also blocks AJAX?...

Actually it also blocks users linking to your webpage using a `<a>` tag, so I wouldn't say it's a very nice one...

Comment: If this works it's probably the best way assuming it doesn't put extra load on your page requests.

Comment: Nice, the `add_header` nginx directive worked like a champ. But this won't protect against `img` or `ajax` requests will it?

Comment: Can I use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` or is that always going to say `web1.mydomain.com`, even though the request may be made from an `img` or AJAX request from a different host?

Comment: @Justin `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is always `web1.mydomain.com` (unless another domain points to your IP and is used instead).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your apache configuration file you could do something like this:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

You might need to add something like this afterwards:

```
<FilesMatch "*\.(css|js|gif|jpg|png)$">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that prevent anybody from executing the script. This is NOT what I want, I want to prevent running the script from a different host than `web1.mydomain.com`.

Comment: No. this prevents anybody except 127.0.0.1 (your server) from executing the file.

Comment: Using `deny all; allow 127.0.0.1;` does not work. It blocks all requests by users.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using nginx hosts configuration. Put following code in all hosts `server` block except one you want to allow execution.

```
  location /myscript {
    deny all;
  }
```